# Can't launch selenium tests inside container, WebDriverException:Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally

Tags: python, bash, selenium, docker

My problem is - I can't launch selenium tests inside container.

my docker file looks like:

```
FROM selenium/node-chrome

EXPOSE 9090


USER root
RUN mkdir /code

WORKDIR /code
ADD requirements_tests.txt /code/
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y python python-dev python-distribute python-pip
RUN pip install -r requirements_tests.txt
ADD /selenium_tests HTMLTestRunner.py launch_selenium_tests.py chromedriver /code/
```

`/selenium_tests` contain all my tests, `launch_selenium_tests.py` - its my launcher for tests.

```
import time
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
import os

class SeleniumTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
            todo add validation for arguments
        :param args:
        :param kwargs:
        """
        super(SeleniumTestCase, self).__init__(args[0])
        self.base_url = args[1]


    def setUp(self):
        chromedriver = "./chromedriver"
        os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='./chromedriver')
        self.display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 800))
        self.display.start()
```

this is my `test_case` file

So, when i start docker container with -it /bin/bash (interactive mode with terminal) and launch tests i get this error msg:

```
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.20.353124 (035346203162d32c80f1dce587c8154a1efa0c3b),platform=Linux 4.2.0-35-generic x86_64)
```

I already try to switch container with selenium, rewrite some lines of code, but nothing worked for me.

Any idea how i can fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest two things:

Quick -  start the `display`before starting the driver so the code:

```
def setUp(self):
    chromedriver = "./chromedriver"
    os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
    self.display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 800))
    self.display.start()
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='./chromedriver')
```

Second I would strongly suggest to use the `service_log_path` and `service_args` arguments to the selenium webdriver to see output from the chromedriver:

```
service_log_path = "{}/chromedriver.log".format(outputdir)
service_args = ['--verbose']
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver',
        service_args=service_args,
        service_log_path=service_log_path)
```

This may provide missing info why the driver failed to start